# I am calling a stored procedure from VBA and then updating data. I get an error while updating. How can I fix that?

Tags: sql-server, vba

This does not work. I don't know why

```vb
' I don't know why I can't edit a recordset using a stored procedure
'blnOK = ExecuteSP(rs, "sp_OneRecord", pintCustID)

If blnOK Then
    If pstrSaveMode = "New" Then
        rs.AddNew
    End If
    
    For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        rs.Fields(i) = Nz(Me(rs.Fields(i).Name)) 'I get an error here
    Next i
    rs.Update
```

This is the stored procedure in SQL Server.

```sql
Select * from dbo.tblDirectory Where CustID = @CustID
```

This is the calling code in VBA that does work

```vb
SQL = "Select * from dbo.tblDirectory where CustID = " & pintCustID & ";"

blnOK = OpenADO(rs, SQL)

If blnOK Then
    If pstrSaveMode = "New" Then
        rs.AddNew
    End If
    
    For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        rs.Fields(i) = Nz(Me(rs.Fields(i).Name))
    Next i
    rs.Update
End If
```

Comment: Your VBA isn't parametrised, you **need** to fix that. Also you say you get an error, however, you forgot to include said error in your question.

Comment: You can't update the results of a stored procedure. Write an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid of that.